# Weird positioning in certain browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, positioning

I'll try to be short and clean. I did website for friend, although she says some people complain about pink quote field to cover the text area, I've tried this on different PCs, browsers but haven't seen this kind of issue. So I was thinking maybe that old IE or something?

Here's websites link: http://www.zlobekbambino.pl

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a service such as [Adobe's Browser Lab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html) or [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/) to test the site in various browsers to see which is causing problems. You can then try to work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Windows PC, you can test with all versions of IE by installing [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It's a very usefull program that allows you to run all versions of IE in tabs in the same window.

Obviously though, it only works on a Windows PC, so if you're on a Mac you won't be able to use it. In that case, http://www.browsershots.org allows you to download screenshots from virtually any browser ever released. The downside of that is that you only get a static screenshot, so not much use for testing dynamic content, but still a useful tool.

Comment: BTW: IE8 and later come with a nice developer mode that allows you to switch to IE7+ compatibility mode. Just press F12 and you'll have an option in the top row of the window that'll appear. I'm not sure that it's 100% accurate, but better than nothing.

Comment: @BlaM - NOTE: IE8's "IE7 compatibility" mode is **not** 100% the same as IE7. There are significant differences in how pages are rendered between the two, plus it has its own bugs that don't appear either in IE7 or IE8-normal-mode. You're far better off testing with a real copy of IE7 (in IETester, for example).

Comment: IETester has it's own problem though. Even if you ignore the crashes there's a lot that doesn't work. But same as for IE8 Debug Mode: Better than nothing ;)